Push notifications subscriptions
I'm working on a web app (React on frontend and NestJS on backend) and I implemented push notifications.
I registered a service worker on the frontend and, upon login, i ask my user for permission for notifications. Once the user allows, a subscription is created of the following type:
{
   endpoint: string;
   keys: {
      p256dh: string;
      auth: string;
   }
}

Then i send this subscription to the backend and store it in the database along with the id of the user that created the subscription (allowed the notifications). When i want to send a notification to this user, i fetch all of their subscriptions from the database and use them to send push notifications via web-push library.
My question is - what does this subscription refer to? The device, the browser, or something else? I noticed when i subscribe as user A and log out, the user's subscription is still active, and if user B logs in using the same browser/device, they will never receive a requestPermission prompt and they will receive user A's notifications.
Is there a way to handle this without unsubscribing upon logout and asking for permission each time the user logs in?

I will cite some useful information from a web.dev article:
"After you get permission, your website needs to initiate the process of subscribing the user to push notifications. This is done through JavaScript, using the Push API. You'll need to provide a public authentication key during the subscription process, which you'll learn more about later. After you kick off the subscription process, the browser makes a network request to a web service known as a push service, which you'll also learn more about later.
Assuming that the subscription was successful, the browser returns a PushSubscription object. You'll need to store this data long-term. Usually this is done by sending the information to a server that you control, and then having the server store it in a database.
Your server doesn't actually send the push message directly to a client. A push service does that. A push service is a web service controlled by your user's browser vendor. When you want to send a push notification to a client you need to make a web service request to a push service. The web service request that you send to the push service is known as a web push protocol request."
So, the subscription to push notifications refers to the browser. Therefore, ALL users using the same browser will receive push notifications. Receiving push notifications does not depend on the current authentication status of users, authentication of users and push notification subscription are completely independent of each other, they are unrelated indeed.
RequestPermission prompt will only be shown again when the browser auto-expires the user's subscription to push notifications or if the user revokes permission manually at some point. There is no JavaScript method/API to revoke the permission once it's granted. Only user can revoke it.
